# TreeSet ordering error

Tags: java, treeset

I have an array called `numb`. It contains 5 numbers (from a user's input) An example of input values are: 5,29,101,100,89.4. I transfer the elements of this array into a `TreeSet` called `ts` using a for loop (I arrange the elements in descending order ). After this I display then elements of this `TreeSet` using a `MessageDialog`. But the display shows something different than what I expect. It displays `[89.4,5,29,101,100]`.

When I put in numbers with the same place value - like tens, hundreds (if the array contains only numbers like 12,56,84,74,65), it orders it as expected. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Here's the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class dollarGUI {

  public static void main(String[] agrs){
    Hello hello=new Hello();
    hello.as();
    hello.Order();
    hello.Display();
  } 
}

class Hello {

  String[]be = new String[5];
  TreeSet<String> ts = new TreeSet<String>(Collections.reverseOrder());

  public String[] as() {
    for(int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
      be[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter number");
    }
    return be;
  }

  public void Order() {
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
      ts.add(be[i]);
    }
  }

  public void Display() {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ts);
  }  
}
```

Comment: Strings and numbers do not have the same sorting order.

Comment: Strings don't sort the same way as numbers.  That's your problem.  It's not a bug; it's a failure to understand lexical comparison of Strings.

Answer (score 2):

You're converting the numbers to strings and thus don't get the natural ordering of numbers but the natural ordering of strings where "10" is smaller than "2", since the first character is smaller.

Change the content of the tree set to `Number` or a specific number type like `Double` and parse the array elements to numbers, 

e.g. by using `Double.parseDouble()`, `new DecimalFormat().parse()` etc..

Answer (score 0):

When you compare strings it is from the first character.  This means you need to think of the "numbers" like this. In reverse order you can have

```
-9.9
-1e1
-100
89.4
899.5
5
29
101
100
05
005.0
0059
```

First you compare the first letter or digit 8 > 5 > 2 > 1.  In the case of a tie, you compare the second letter and so on. Note: '.' > '9' and '-' > '9'

The way to compare these as number, is to convert them to numbers first.